# Chrome: CSS & JS transition not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have three images `img1`, `img2` and `img3` ( 3 images ). It's initial position is -50% absolute top right and left respectively. When I change the position to `static`, with transition `2s` it actualy needs to moved to center.

**Problem** While the transiton is taking place, the is snapping in some chrome ( in some laptop's chrome ). I know what is making the transition breaking.

This is my jQuery code.

```
        $(".middle-fixed-coming-soon-top").css({"top": "0px"});
        $(".middle-fixed-coming-soon-top").one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',  function(e) {
            $(".middle-fixed-coming-soon-top").css({"position": "static"});
            // code to execute after transition ends
        });

        $(".middle-fixed-organics-left").css({"left": "333px"});
        $(".middle-fixed-organics-left").one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',  function(e) {
            $(".middle-fixed-organics-left").css({"position": "static"});
            $(".middle-fixed-organics-left .for-margin").css("margin-top", "auto");
            // code to execute after transition ends
        });

        $(".middle-fixed-tagline-right").css({"right": "333px"});
        $(".middle-fixed-tagline-right").one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',  function(e) {
            $(".middle-fixed-tagline-right").css({"position": "static"});
            $(".middle-fixed-tagline-right .for-margin").css("margin-top", "auto");
            // code to execute after transition ends
        });
```

I am new to jQuery. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

**EDITS**
This happends when I reload second time or more.

Comment: In which version does it not work?

Comment: Because your transition uses absolute pixels which means the transition works perfectly, but only at precisely one exact screen width - 1360px

Comment: It's `Version 51.0.2704.79 Built on Ubuntu 14.04`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest thing I'm noticing is that you're switching an element from position: absolute to position: static. This means it switches from not influencing the surrounding content, to pushing everything else out of the way. I'd use relative instead of absolute, and take out the static switch entirely. From there, you should just need to re-kerjigger the left/top positioning. The code below should handle all of the JS end, just the CSS needs position: absolute to switch to position: relative.

```
        $(".middle-fixed-coming-soon-top").css({"top": "0px"});
        $(".middle-fixed-coming-soon-top").one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',  function(e) {
            // code to execute after transition ends
        });

        $(".middle-fixed-left").css({"left": "0px"});
        $(".middle-fixed-left").one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',  function(e) {
            $(".middle-fixed-left .for-margin").css("margin-top", "auto");
            // code to execute after transition ends
        });

        $(".middle-fixed-tagline-right").css({"right": "0px"});
        $(".middle-fixed-tagline-right").one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',  function(e) {
            $(".middle-fixed-tagline-right .for-margin").css("margin-top", "auto");
            // code to execute after transition ends
        });
```

Comment: Then why it only work in private tab and not in normal tabs? It's weird. I cleared cache too. So I need to convert everything to relative???

Comment: If you just remove the css({"position": "static"}); from your JS and change .middle-fixed-coming-soon-top, .middle-fixed-triesta-organics-left, and .middle-fixed-tagline-right from position: absolute to position: relative, it should fix the jump. But you will need to adjust the left/top positioning for the end states in your JS a little to compensate.

Comment: I just edited the code you posted to handle the position changes, swapping that in and doing the absolute to relative fix in your CSS should work and handle any screen size.

Comment: Thanks, I have made the change but i still see the lag.

Comment: It looks like there's something in there that is setting different values for the left/right animations based on your screen size

Comment: I don't think so. I hard clear cache, but still snapping.

Comment: Starting at line 61 and ending at line 86 (aside from the conditional closing tag) of comingsoon.js you'll see there's a conditional applying the old logic if your screen is under 1024px wide. You can just remove that, the above code should handle all screen sizes.

Comment: I removed it, still the lag. Thanks

Comment: You're animating from 153px to auto - try switching auto to 0

Comment: Yes, just commented it out. I don't know why it is happening.!

Comment: After you did that I'm not seeing any more snapping - it seems to animate in correctly on all sizes & browsers

Comment: It is better now. Thanks for help :)